# Upload Datasource using Tabcmd

Tags: tableau-api

I have a file loaded through excel. How can I publish that datasource through tabcmd command.

I have seen syntax where it says to use *.tde. is there are way to decide a workbook automatically that it uses excel as a source so that I don't need to extract datasource in the form of tde and use tabcmd to publish my datasource.

Comment: Hi, Have u created any views using tableau and published in the server or Do you want to publish only the datasource?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish a datasource, tde is the only possible format you can use. Tabcmd isn't currently able to upload any other formats.
There are two simple ways to convert your excel file to tde:

- Load it as datasource in Tableau Desktop and Data -> "name of your excel" -> Extract data
- Use [Tableau Data Extract API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_TDE_API.html) to programmatically generate tde file.

The you can publish the tde file using tabcmd as described in [documentation](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm).